# Resetting autoincrement in h2

Tags: java, playframework, h2

I'm testing a controller that returns a json response but the tests
fail after the first time because the h2 database does not reset the
auto increment id.
Using fixtures or creating objects manually has a same problem.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Fixtures.deleteAllModels();
    Fixtures.loadModels("data.yaml");
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 26):

Start your play app, fire up browser with this url (if you run play app locally):

```
http://localhost:9000/@db
```

Enter your h2 db, and type the command below and run:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ALTER COLUMN <column_name> RESTART WITH 1
```

If you'd like to do this programmatically, `Fixtures.executeSQL()` might be useful

For more information, check http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_alter

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring, I found this [blog post](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-resetting-auto-increment-columns-before-each-test-method/) which suggests using `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`

So that each test uses a new application context, thereby resetting the db increments.

Comment: This will make the tests super slow

Answer (score 2):

Execute an SQL-script on your table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE my_table RESTART IDENTITY;
ALTER SEQUENCE my_table_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

H2 should be of version 1.4.200 or higher.

See https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html